# How can i change the Debezium default topic naming convention to make it fit for confluent hive table auto-generated strategy?

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

I am build an data synchronizer, which capture the data change from MySQL Source, and export the data to hive.

I choose to use Kafka Connect to implement this. I use [Debezium](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/tutorial.html) as source connector, and [confluent hdfs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html#quickstart) as sink connector.

But the problem is, the Debezium's naming convention for Kafka topic is like:

`serverName.databaseName.tableName`

In confluent hdfs sink propeties, i have to config the `topics` the same as Debezium generated:

`"topics": "serverName.databaseName.tableName"`

Confluent hdfs sink connector will generate path in HDFS like:

`/topics/serverName.databaseName.tableName/partition=0`

which will definitely cause some problem in HDFS/Hive, since the path contains syntax `.`, In fact, the external table auto generated by confluent hdfs sink connector failed, due to the path problem.

```java
2020-05-08T00:42:02,717 ERROR [pool-6-thread-31] metastore.RetryingHMSHandler: MetaException(message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: hdfs://localhost:9000./null/topics/dbserver1.test_data_1.student1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newMetaException(HiveMetaStore.java:6935)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:2050)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.create_table_with_environment_context(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$create_table_with_environment_context.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:14800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$create_table_with_environment_context.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:14784)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor$1.run(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor$1.run(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:107)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor.process(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:119)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: hdfs://localhost:9000./null/topics/dbserver1.test_data_1.student1
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDnsPath(Warehouse.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDnsPath(Warehouse.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1852)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:2035)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: hdfs://localhost:9000./null/topics/dbserver1.test_data_1.student1
    at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:260)
    ... 26 more
```

So is there anyway that i can change the Debezium default naming convention for topics, or, can i change the default path that confluent hdfs sink connector generated through the topic name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDFS Connector will [replace dots (and dashes) with underscores when creating Hive tables](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/385aa1cf3435ab2318c719b6b059ec90bfe9e47f/hive/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/hive/HiveMetaStore.java#L367-L369)

HDFS itself doesn't care about dots in paths. The problem is that you cannot have a dot after the port, and you have `/null` in there somehow.

`hdfs://localhost:9000./null`

---

> is there anyway that i can change the Debezium default naming convention for topics

Solution has nothing to do with Debezium. You can use `RegexRouter` that is base Apache Kafka Connect library in a `transforms` config for you source or sink connector, depending on how early you want to "fix" the problem.

You could also write your own transform and put it in Connect's `plugin.path`